# Codename One - Color of a pressed button on iOS

Tags: codenameone

I have the following very simple code:

```
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
    Button button = new Button("Click me", "MyButtonUIID");
    hi.add(button);
    hi.show();
```

The following code is my theme.xml:

```
<resource majorVersion="1" minorVersion="9" useXmlUI="false">
    <theme name="Theme">
        <val key="@includeNativeBool" value="true" />
        <val key="MyButtonUIID.bgColor" value="ff3300" />
        <val key="MyButtonUIID.press#bgColor" value="ff66" />
        <val key="MyButtonUIID.press#transparency" value="255" />
        <val key="MyButtonUIID.sel#bgColor" value="ff66" />
        <val key="MyButtonUIID.sel#transparency" value="255" />
        <val key="MyButtonUIID.transparency" value="255" />
    </theme>
</resource>
```

On every Android version from 4.4 to 8 (and in the Simulator **with Android and iPhone skins**) I get a red button that becomes green while it's pressed (during all the time that it's pressed).
On every iOS version from 8 to 11 I get a button that is **always red** (or sometimes it becomes green for a very very short moment).

So... how can I get in iOS the same behavior of Android and of the Simulator? Am I missing something or is it a bug?

Comment: Try `button.setLegacyRenderer(true)` does it workaround the issue? If so this is a bug in the fast rendering pipeline

Comment: No, `button.setLegacyRenderer(true)` doesn't workaround the issue. I've filed the bug: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2334 In the bug report, I attached three videos of the button on the simulator, on Google Pixel 2 and on iPhone X